# Can you pull from before a casted time

Tags: sql

sql newbie here. I'm trying to make a report for a tracking software where assets go into the database with a "Status" and a time stamp when they make that change.

What I'm trying to do is write a report that tells me when something hits the status 'complete' but its origin status was a month prior. How would I go about getting this to work properly with declaring a start and end date?

```
Declare @StartDate datetime
Declare @EndDate datetime

-- Set the start and end dates here  yyyy-mm-dd --
set @StartDate = '2021-08-01'
set @EndDate = '2021-08-31'
 Select *
 from assetcurrent.dbo ac
 inner join (select assetid, min(hdate) as [hdate] from history where hstatus = "created" group by assetid, hdate) ah

Where a.status in ('complete')
and cast(ac.hdate as date) <= cast(@EndDate as date)
    and cast(ac.hdate as date) >= cast(@StartDate as date)
    and ah.hdate < dateadd(month, -1, @StartDate)
    
order by [Report number]
```

Am I properly using dateadd here in the where clauses? I just get 0 results when I know there should be at least a few.

Thanks!

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include a concrete example.  That is, some demo/example data, and then the results you'd like for the demo data.  More explanation is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is using product specific functions.)

Comment: Please clarify for month prior.  Ex, something ordered on Sept 30 and Completed on Oct 1 is only 1 day, yet in the prior month.  Is your question really what projects too longer than, ex: 30 days, to be completed?  Much more specific condition.  Also, are you looking for completed tasks such as Completed within September 2021 that took more than 30 days from the order/project start date?

Answer (score 1):

`--and ah.hdate < dateadd(month, -1, @StartDate)`

Was what i was trying and giving me failed results.

`and MONTH(ac.hdate) != month(ah.hdate)`

Is what i should have used instead. much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Please clarify for month prior. Ex, something ordered on Sept 30 and Completed on Oct 1 is only 1 day, yet in the prior month. Is your question really what projects too longer than, ex: 30 days, to be completed? Much more specific condition. Also, are you looking for completed tasks such as Completed within September 2021 that took more than 30 days from the order/project start date?

```
select 
        AC.*,
        PQ.DateCreated,
        PQ.DateCompleted
    from 
        ( select 
                h.assetid, 
                MIN( h2.hdate) as DateCreated,
                min(h.hdate) as DateCompleted,
            from 
                history h
                    JOIN history h2
                       ON h.assetid = h2.assetid
                       AND h2.status = 'created'
                    AND h2.hdate < dateadd( month, -1, h.hdate )
            where 
                    h.hstatus = 'complete'
                AND h.hdate >= '2021-09-01'
                AND h.hdate < '2021-10-01'
            group by 
                h.assetid ) PQ
        JOIN AssetCurrent AC
            ON PQ.assetid = AC.assetid
    order by
        ac.[Report Number]
```

So, in the query above, I am starting to look for all orders COMPLETED within the given time period (changed to Sept 1 to Sept 30).  From that, I joined secondary to same history table again with alias `h2` on the same asset ID, but this time based on when it was originally created.  Now, I have a record of complete and created that I am looking at.  From that, I can now apply the h2.date being LESS than a month prior to its creation.  So in an example of an order was complete on Sept 27, it would only return the same asset if it was ordered prior to Oct 27, thus took more than a month to complete.

Once I had that part resolved, I could then join to your `AssetCurrent` table based on an implied key of `assetid` to get those details.  While at it, I grabbed both context of Created and Completed Dates in the return set.